# How to catch all http method in routes file @ playframework2.4.x?

Tags: playframework-2.4

I have many many controllers in the project, each function supports both GET and POST method, How to do this? I really don't like to write twice like this:

```
GET     /admin/orders/something                           controllers.admin.OrdersController.something()
POST     /admin/orders/something                       controllers.admin.OrdersController.something()
```

And if I put '*', the error occurs:

```
Compilation error
string matching regex `\z' expected but `*' found
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can't, and for readability it is sometimes better to repeat things. Putting `*` instead of `GET` and `POST` would allow `DELETE`, `PATCH`...

Comment: and is there any possible to write like this?

`(GET|POST) /aaa/bbb controllers.Aaa.bbb`